# What age to bring kids to graveyard

Tags: practical-islam, children, grave

My son grandma passed away and he is 3 years old. I wanted to ask what age should we bring kid to grave yard as there is a dispute in my family and I know that 3-4 is too small to bring them here. What Quran say about it.?

Comment: The qur'an say nothing about it. If that is all you want to know I can post it as an answer.

Comment: I guess going to a graveyard is fine. Sharing/expaining all the details or showing a dead body isn't fine. Kids can sense a bad/tense situation even though they're not able to fully grasp all its details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Quran does not say anything about it as far as I know.

We visit graveyard to be reminded of death, to pray for forgiveness of the deceased or to receive tabarruk. Not one of these apply to a 3 year old as he is too young to understand anything and not mukallaf, so there is no interest served by bringing him to a graveyard.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the Islam SE. What is mukallaf and how can one argue that "the child should know, what is life and where we go" or "realities of life"